# Angular Material nested node Tree Table

Tags: angular, angular-material, tree, angular-material-table

Trying to integrate material tree with material table, I found that following that does it very well but uses flat nodes to achieve a tree table.

Flat Node Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m77g7e-semvxp?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

For my use case I need to keep the nested nodes and get the table to work with Material's nested tree nodes, I've able to modify the above example to partiality work with nested nodes but I am unable to get the nodes to toggle. How do I manually toggle a node when using nested tree?

My Nested TreeTable Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m77g7e-ql7zqz?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,app%2Ftable-basic-example.css,app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried similar and could not get it to work using the NestedTreeControl. However, I found below answer that worked for me as even though it uses the FlatTreeControl, the data is still in nested objects which is what I needed (same as your example's data):

[angular material table with a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913473/angular-material-table-with-a-tree)